# Switch content between divs on refresh and/or timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a simple page with 4 divs, each containing an image uploaded to a database.

I'd like for the image in each div to change when someone refreshes the page (and eventually after a few minutes of navigation), so that each time you open the page, the picture inside each  will be different.

For example: I have 10 images

```
1° time: div1(img1), div2(img2), div3(img3), div4(img4)

2° time: div1(img9), div2(img6), div3(img8), div4(img3)

3° time: div1(img1), div2(img4), div3(img10), div4(img5)
```

and so on.. The trickiest part, is that there shouldn't be the same image twice, so let's say it should never happen:

```
div1(img1), div2(img2), div3(img3), div4(img1)
```

EDIT: So this happened:
demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grbwvx
I was moving around divs, and they are supposed to be squares (which they are, if I don't put the images in it).. But when the images are loaded, it screws up my css. I tried removing margins and stuff like that, but nothing worked.
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: You haven't posted your code, but the solution seems pretty simple. If you need help with the function selecting the unique random images post the code you came up with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to serve unique images from the database on each interval. If you are trying to avoid using SQL/MySQL, let's assume you have a list (an array) on the page ready.

HTML:

```
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
<button>reload</button>
```

JQuery:

```
/* generate the array of images you want to choose from */
var srcarray = [
  "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/7e/1d/4a/7e1d4a1566976f139a2ba58b108e2bce.jpg",
  "http://rs832.pbsrc.com/albums/zz248/Paria53/Edited/Random.jpg~c200",
  "http://images.freeimages.com/images/premium/large-thumbs/5187/51875120-random-numbers-forming-a-sphere.jpg",
  "http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/community/land-random.png",
  "http://d2894izlucyd11.cloudfront.net/images/p/88/27/08/dd/7df9039478fe4a238746d1acd38a980e.jpg",
  "http://t10.deviantart.net/lGgxLge7u3hucL5OBoZkiDvnnqA=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre15/5fe0/th/pre/f/2008/191/1/9/random_by_d_faultx.png",
  "http://www.moooi.com/sites/default/files/styles/project_thumb_product/public/thumb-image/randomledfloorm.jpg?itok=2wIu1tk6",
  "http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/25200000/Colorful-Bokeh-Lights-random-25230232-200-200.gif",
  "http://t00.deviantart.net/YWdrXj-21kfzc-IMLSli2UmdhGU=/300x200/filters:fixed_height(100,100):origin()/pre13/93b0/th/pre/f/2010/044/b/4/random_space_invaider_by_random_liquo.jpg",
  "http://www.islandstone.com/mediafiles/product_records/56_Random_lines_thumb.jpg"
];

function randomizeImages() {
  arr = [];
  /* select unique images from the array and display them into relevant divs (any number divs allowed, should be less than available images)*/
  while(arr.length < $("section div").length){
    var randomnumber= srcarray[Math.floor(Math.random()*srcarray.length)];
    var found=false;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
       if(arr[i]==randomnumber){found=true;break}
    }
    if(!found)arr[arr.length]=randomnumber;
    $( "section div:nth-child("+(i+1)+")" ).html( '<img src="'+randomnumber+'">' );
  };
}

//randomize images when page is reloaded
$(function() {
 randomizeImages();
});
//randomize images when clicking a reload button (for display purposes only)
$("button").click ( function() {
  randomizeImages(); 
});
//randomize images every 5 seconds (change interval as you wish)
window.setInterval(function(){
  randomizeImages(); 
}, 5000);
```

I made a demo for you: http://codepen.io/VsevolodTS/pen/KzPdpX

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly!
I'm just starting with JS, so even stuff "this simple" is a whole new world to me..